# SQL: connecting tables that have no relation

Tags: sql

If i have two tables that have nothing in common

I want to do a select as follows:

```
column from table1, column from table 2
```

How do I do it?

Comment: what database back-end are you using?

Comment: If they have no relation to each other, how would the database know which rows to line up side-by-side?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work in SQL Server assuming you want the Cartesian Product

```
SELECT A.Column, B.Column
FROM TableA A, TableB B
```

Answer (score 2):

Try a `UNION ALL`

`SELECT columnA FROM table1 UNION ALL SELECT columnB from table2`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT table1.column, table2.column 
FROM table1, table2
```

gives you the cartesian product. Not really sure if that's what you need though?

Answer (score 1):

Meaning, you want the [cartesian](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product) product of the two tables?

Look at doing a [CROSS JOIN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Cross_join).

Answer (score 1):

If both tables have a single row this isn't a big issue:

```
SELECT ( SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE1 ) AS COL1, ( SELECT COLUMN1 FROM TABLE2 ) AS COL2;
```

See the other answers for the cartesian product and this link which is weary of them:

http://www.rampant-books.com/t_hpsdba_77_cartesian_join_operations.htm

Answer (score 1):

If you're not concerned with the columns appears beside each other AND the data types are compatible, you can use UNION.

```
SELECT columnA FROM table1
UNION
SELECT columnB FROM table2
```

Comment: Clarification on this technique ... using UNION keyword will remove duplicates from the results. If you want duplicates, then use UNION ALL instead, which concatenates the two table result sets.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you can't *really* unless both tables have have zero or one row then you can use Jacob G's answer.

Otherwise, 3 rows in one and 2 rows in another will give the Cartesian product = 6 rows.

If you don't want the cross/Cartesian product then you're asking for a jagged recordset which is not possible. How should rows from one table relate to a row in the other table?

If they are truly unrelated, it's 2 separate calls...